# How could I populate a ListView with items from an external WordPress site?

Tags: android, wordpress, list, listview, external

I'm trying to populate a listview with titles from an external wordpress site, which will in turn each become links to each post. I have no idea how to make this happen.

I have a php script behind the wordpress site that can pull the titles and the contents of the posts that I want. How can I use this?

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you familiar with JSOUP or any parser? This is what you will need. also post the link to the items you want to retrieve. Ill see if i can parse the titles for you and use a listIrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to Parse the information or the titles. [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/) is the more common and works very well. I use this for several projects.